# CSS: 100% width and margin

Tags: css

Please see example at

http://jsfiddle.net/cne94hw4/

```
.a{
      width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

I was expecting "width 100%" will mean 100% of the windows, but clearly it's not when I add a margin to it. I found this is difficult to understand.

What's the exact relationship of the box and the margin? It's there any written rule for this?

Comment: By default, the `width` of an element only describes its content and not border, margin, or padding. So adding `margin` will appear to increase an element's width. This might be helpful: [MDN Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about the CSS Box model, which is described in detail at the CSS specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

In brief, the `width` defines the width of the content box.  If you add padding, borders
and margins, then the overall width of the block box is the width of the content box plus
any widths due to padding, borders and margins.

As for the `height`, padding and border widths are added to the overall heigth of the
block.  Margins, though, can collapse with the margins of adjacent blocks, which is
another topic to look at (see: **collapsing margins**).

Another concept is the **block formatting context**, which comes into play if you 
deal with elements that may be floated or positioned.

In your example, the overall width of the `a` element is 100% plus 200px due to the
left margin.

Finally, you can have some control over how the width is computed by using the **box-sizing** property.

Answer (score 0):

`width: 100%' does mean`100%` of the document  your example, but you also set a margin, which is what's limiting the width of the element. See what happens when you remove it.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
.class{  
   width:100%;
   padding-left:200px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**margin** adds extra space out of the box.

Comment: Margin is outside of the border box, so adding that will not help with the element's overall width (including margins) exceeding 100% of the viewport.